# formatar colunas de uma tabela a partir de um Array de objetos armazenados no localstorage?

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde! Estou estudando sobre Arrays e objetos e rersolvi criar uma tabela onde eu pego os valores de um input, salvo no localstorage e depois monto a tabela.
Eu consigo capturar, salvar e resgatar os valores, mas não consegui criar as colunas dinamicamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que a tabela ficasse assim:(cada vez que adicionar medida e data, criasse uma coluna).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas o resultado tá sendo esse!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será que alguém pode me a ajudar nessa formatação!

Segue parte do código:

```
    <form class="col s12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="md1" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="md1">Md1</label>
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="md2" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="md2">Md2</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <form class="col s12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="md3" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="md3">Md3</label>
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="md4" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="md4">Md4</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

     <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabelaMedidas">
       <thead>
          <tr>         
            <th scope="col">Nome</th>
            <th scope="col">10/12/20</th>
            <th scope="col">10/01/21</th>
            
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Md1</th>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Md2</th>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Md3</th>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Md4</th>
            <td></td>
          </tr> 
         
         
      
        </tbody> 
      </table>


    function pegarMedidas(){
    let data = new Date();
    let dia = String(data.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    let mes = String(data.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    let ano = data.getFullYear();
    let hora = data.getHours();        
    let min  = data.getMinutes(); 
    dataAtual = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano + '-' + hora + '-' + min; 
   
  
    obj.md1 = document.getElementById('md1').value;
    obj.md2 = document.getElementById('md2').value;
    obj.md3 = document.getElementById('md3').value;
    obj.md4 = document.getElementById('md4').value;
    obj.data = dataAtual;
    medidas.push(obj);
    localStorage.setItem('medidas', JSON.stringify(medidas));  
};

    
 let arr = medidas.map(function(obj) {
 return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
return obj[key];
});
 });

 var minhaTabela = document.getElementById('tabelaMedidas');

 var tBody = minhaTabela.tBodies[0]; 

 for (i = 0; i < tBody.rows.length; i++) {  
     
     tBody.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = arr;
 }
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score -3):

Vou tentar te ajudar partindo do teu resultado.

O problema acontece aqui.

```
tBody.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = arr;
```

tu só muda a linha usando a variável 'i', mas e a coluna é sempre 1? Por isso acaba indo tudo pra primeira coluna. Eu acredito que tu precisa ter outro for dentro pra fazer um loop nas colunas.

Comment: Valeu! Vou tentar aqui. Uma hora vai, rs!